# Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'Suggestion' cannot be null

Tags: php, sql, prepared-statement

Every time I try to press submit without typing anything in the suggestion box on my website, the website is supposed to deny the blank box from the SQL suggestions database and display an error, but when pressing Ok to the alert, it quickly displays an error saying `'Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'Suggestion' cannot be null' in /home/u611142741/public_html/suggestions.php:41'`.

Here is my PHP code:

```
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost", "u611142741_list", "REDACTED"); 
mysql_select_db("u611142741_sugge", $conn);

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=u611142741_sugge;","u611142741_list","REDACTED");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// If the form has been submitted
if (trim($_POST["suggestion543"]) == "") {
  echo "Error";
  echo '<script language="javascript">';
  echo 'alert("Invalid entry! Try Again.")';
  echo '</script>';
  echo '<script>';
  echo 'setTimeout(function(){ window.location="http://musicoro.tk/suggestion-form/" }, 500)';
  echo '</script>';
} else {
  $suggestion = $_POST['suggestion543'];
  $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  echo "Thank you for submitting your suggestion!";
  echo '<script>';
  echo 'setTimeout(function(){ window.location="http://musicoro.tk/suggestion-form/" }, 2000)';
  echo '</script>';
};



// Build an sql statment to add the student details
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO suggestions

(`Suggestion`, `IP Address`) VALUES

(:suggestion, :ip)');

$stmt->bindParam(':suggestion', $suggestion, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':ip', $ip, PDO::PARAM_STR);
try {
        $stmt->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
}

$result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);


// close connection 
mysql_close($conn);
```

And this was put into my error logs:

```
[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'Suggestion' cannot be null' in /home/u611142741/public_html/suggestions.php:41
Stack trace:
#0 /home/u611142741/public_html/suggestions.php(41): PDOStatement->execute()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/u611142741/public_html/suggestions.php on line 41
[22-Nov-2014 22:59:06 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'Suggestion' cannot be null' in /home/u611142741/public_html/suggestions.php:41
Stack trace:
#0 /home/u611142741/public_html/suggestions.php(41): PDOStatement->execute()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/u611142741/public_html/suggestions.php on line 41
```

Got any ideas?

Comment: You're not trapping the empty suggestion. You're looking for it, echoing some Javascript, then just carrying on and attempting to insert the data anyway. The database is doing what it should. The Javascript you're echoing to the client won't stop the PHP code from continuing to execute.

Comment: Any ideas of how to fix it?

Comment: A simple `exit` just before your `else` will halt the script in its tracks and prevent the error. I'm not sure what the client will make of what you've echoed to it, though. You have other problems here. For example, why are you opening and closing a `mysql_*()` connection when you're using PDO?

Comment: I just haven't gotten rid of it since i've used the prepared statements, and by 'other problems' is that the only one or is there more?